# XPath doesn't point to the right HTML table elements with iterator (Scrapy)

Tags: python, xpath, web-crawler, scrapy

I have a problem using XPath to select HTML elements with Scrapy from the table. 
The exemple that I am using is very basic example from Scrapy website: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html and the website that I want to parse would be http://www.euroleague.net/main/results/showgame?gamecode=5&gamenumber=1&phasetypecode=RS&seasoncode=E2013#!playbyplay

At first I used this code:

```
from basketbase.items import BasketbaseItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse


class Basketspider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "playbyplay"
    download_delay = 0.5

    allowed_domains = ["www.euroleague.net"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.euroleague.net/main/results/showgame?gamenumber=1&phasetypecode=RS&gamecode=4&seasoncode=E2013"]
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(),),callback='parse_item',),        
    )  


    def parse(self,response):
        response = HtmlResponse(url=response.url, status=response.status, headers=response.headers, body=response.body)
        return super(Basketspider,self).parse(response)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        response = HtmlResponse(url=response.url, status=response.status, headers=response.headers, body=response.body)
        sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        items=[]
        item = BasketbaseItem()         
        item['game_time'] = sel.select('//div[@style="overflow: auto; height: 250px; width: 800px;"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/text()').extract() #
        item['game_event'] = sel.select('//div[@style="overflow: auto; height: 250px; width: 800px;"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/text()').extract() #
        item['game_event_res_home'] = sel.select('//div[@style="overflow: auto; height: 250px; width: 800px;"]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/text()').extract() #
        item['game_event_res_visitor'] = sel.select('//div[@style="overflow: auto; height: 250px; width: 800px;"]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/text()').extract() #
        item['game_event_team'] = sel.select('//div[@style="overflow: auto; height: 250px; width: 800px;"]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/text()').extract() #
        item['game_event_player'] = sel.select('//div[@style="overflow: auto; height: 250px; width: 800px;"]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/text()').extract() #          
        items.append(item)



        return items
```

*Well it is basic and rules isn't very correct at this moment but the main concern with this example is XPath.*

And it works but not in the way that I want.
**I would like that every item extracted only one value of td per tr** but with this code it extracts all td elements to the item at once.
Item game_event_res_visitor:

```
'game_event_res_visitor': [u'0-0',
                           u'0-0',
                           u'0-0',.......(list goes on and on)
```

To get the result that I want, I decided to use loop (like in Scrapy tutorial (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)), but it doesn't return any values at all. Here is the code:

```
def parse(self,response):
    response = HtmlResponse(url=response.url, status=response.status, headers=response.headers, body=response.body)
    return super(Basketspider,self).parse(response)

def parse_item(self, response):
    response = HtmlResponse(url=response.url, status=response.status, headers=response.headers, body=response.body)
    sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('//div[@style="overflow: auto; height: 250px; width: 800px;"]/table/tbody/tr')        
    items=[]
    item = BasketbaseItem()
    for site in sites:

        item = BasketbaseItem()
        item['game_time'] = sel.select('td[1]/text()').extract() #
        item['game_event'] = sel.select('td[2]/text()').extract() #
        item['game_event_res_home'] = sel.select('td[3]/text()').extract() #
        item['game_event_res_visitor'] = sel.select('td[3]/text()').extract() #
        item['game_event_team'] = sel.select('td[4]/text()').extract() #
        item['game_event_player'] = sel.select('td[5]/text()').extract() #          
        items.append(item)



    return items
```

and terminal output:

```
2014-03-07 16:57:45+0200 [playbyplay] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.euroleague.net/main/results/showgame?gamecode=9&gamenumber=1&phasetypecode=RS&seasoncode=E2013>
    {'game_event': [],
     'game_event_player': [],
     'game_event_res_home': [],
     'game_event_res_visitor': [],
     'game_event_team': [],
     'game_time': []}
2014-03-07 16:57:45+0200 [playbyplay] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.euroleague.net/main/results/showgame?gamecode=9&gamenumber=1&phasetypecode=RS&seasoncode=E2013>
    {'game_event': [],
     'game_event_player': [],
     'game_event_res_home': [],
     'game_event_res_visitor': [],
     'game_event_team': [],
     'game_time': []}
```

I understand that something wrong is with my XPath, but I don't understand what. If I use relative XPath in item elements it gives me the same results as I reached with first example. So it is out there, but I can't reach it with that code that I have. I even tried "wild card".

```
    item['game_time'] = sel.select('*/text()').extract() #
    item['game_event'] = sel.select('*/text()').extract() #
    item['game_event_res_home'] = sel.select('*/text()').extract() #
    item['game_event_res_visitor'] = sel.select('*/text()').extract() #
    item['game_event_team'] = sel.select('*/text()').extract() #
    item['game_event_player'] = sel.select('*/text()').extract() #
```

It failed to get any text results.

```
2014-03-07 19:11:14+0200 [playbyplay] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.euroleague.net/main/results/showgame?gamecode=7&gamenumber=1&phasetypecode=RS&seasoncode=E2013>
    {'game_event': [u' \r\n', u'\r\n'],
     'game_event_player': [u' \r\n', u'\r\n'],
     'game_event_res_home': [u' \r\n', u'\r\n'],
     'game_event_res_visitor': [u' \r\n', u'\r\n'],
     'game_event_team': [u' \r\n', u'\r\n'],
     'game_time': [u' \r\n', u'\r\n']}
```

I am confused and I don't understand what is wrong with my XPath or my code.

Comment: See http://www.sscce.org/ for hints on writing better questions -- isolating something to **only** the minimum code necessary to reproduce a problem helps a great deal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what works for me:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    response = HtmlResponse(url=response.url, status=response.status, headers=response.headers, body=response.body)
    sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    rows = sel.select('//div[@style="overflow: auto; height: 250px; width: 800px;"]/table/tbody/tr')
    for row in rows:
        item = BasketbaseItem()
        item['game_time'] = row.select("td[1]/text()").extract()[0]
        item['game_event'] = row.select("td[2]/text()").extract()[0]
        result = row.select("td[3]/text()").extract()[0]
        item['game_event_res_home'], item['game_event_res_visitor'] = result.split('-')
        item['game_event_team'] = row.select("td[4]/text()").extract()[0]
        item['game_event_player'] = row.select("td[5]/text()").extract()[0]
        yield item
```

Here's an example item I'm getting:

```
{'game_event': u'Steal',
 'game_event_player': u'DJEDOVIC, NIHAD',
 'game_event_res_home': u'0 ',
 'game_event_res_visitor': u' 0',
 'game_event_team': u'FC Bayern Munich',
 'game_time': u'2'}
```

For you, it's just a start though - sometimes items are not yielded due to `IndexError` exception - handle it properly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes it gives IndexError due to "<strong>" element used to mark events when points are made during the game. But right now spider works.